# how can i send a value to other page via POST without Input Tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, input, prepared-statement

How can I send a value to another page via POST without Input Tag in PHP?
I tried this way but also it didn't work.

[image: the assisment]
[image: the code]

```
<?php
include("database/config.php");
include("database/opendb.php");
include("functions.php");


if (isset($_POST["totalHobbies"])) {
    $par = $_POST["totalHobbies"];
}

$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, hobbies, id ";
$query .= "FROM persons ";
$query .= "WHERE hobbies = ? ";

$preparendquery = $dbaselink->prepare($query);
$preparendquery->bind_param("i", $par);
$preparendquery->execute();
if ($preparendquery->errno) {
    echo "Fout bij uitvoeren commando". "<br>";
} else {
    $result = $preparendquery->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
        echo "Geen rijen gevoenden" . "<br>" ;
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    // here is the problem
            echo "<form action=\"details.php\" method='POST' >";    //refer to details.php page
            $id = $row["id"];
            echo "<a href=\"details.php?id= " . $row['id'] . " \">" . fullname($row['firstname'], $row['lastname']). "</a>". "<br>";
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name = \"id\" value= '$id'> </input>";
            echo "</form>";
        };
    }
}
$preparendquery->close();

echo"<br><button onclick=\"location.href='index.html'\">Back</button>";
include("database/closedb.php");
?>
```

Comment: i do not understand your question

Comment: i just want to send the value of (id) with POST ( to details.php) but without Input tag,
i tried to make the input tag hidden but it did;t work

Comment: any reason why? It doesn't sound practical in anyway to me

Comment: because it's a link, and i want when i click on it, it will display the details of this person(in the link)
so i can't use input and i need the id to bring the details from the database and display it according to the id

Comment: Are you required to use a `POST` request?

Comment: you need to look at ajax requests and do it via javascript.

Comment: the assignment is about post and preparendquery, but for this part there is no preference I think, do you know other way?

Comment: i tried GET method and it works,
thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send form with 'a href'. You can use button or input button and style it to look like a regular link (correct solution). Or you can use Javascript to handle link click and send form from javascript (bad workaround, but also working one).

Also if you want to get informations, you should use GET method which will also solve your problem.

Comment: i tried GET method and it works,
thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Momen if you are using get method, you don't need form at all - `<a href="details.php?id=1"Link</a>` means you are passing parameter id via GET method.

Comment: Correct, I deleted the Form, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand your question properly.

Remove the `<a>` tag

Your input tag is not written properly. It should be

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name = \"id\" value= '$id'/>";
```

Comment: the assignment requires to use a link
i need it to make it as a link and when i click on it will display the details of this person(in the link)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `id` as a session variable then call it in details.php page.